# data type trouble in php

Tags: php

I don't know why but the data type in this code makes a trouble when the id in the url starts with the number zero like this:
http://localhost/exp/update.php?id=03A43
In this case the id is 03A43.

And my query looks like this:

```
mysql_select_db("school", $con);
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO=".(int)$_GET['id']);

?>
```

There is no problem in the design if the id does not start with the number zero.
What might be the proper data type for numbers beginning in zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote your string:

```
mysql_select_db("school", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='".$_GET['id']."'")
```

Comment: QUICK, everyone visit `http://localhost/exp/update.php?id=%27%3B--%0ADROP+TABLE+student+CASCADE%3B` .  Seriously, the string needs to be escaped with `mysql_escape_string`.

Comment: It would probably be even better if one were to use mysqli and prepared statements no?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** The OP didn't reveal until recently that the type of the field is a varchar, not a number.  Hence, s/he should use this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='"
           . mysql_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'");
```

For posterity, my original answer was:

---

It looks like you're trying to parse a hexadecimal number, in which case you could do:

```
hexdec($_GET['id'])
```

`(int)x` is the same as `intval(x)`, which defaults to base 10.  Your number, `03A43`, was clearly not base 10, so PHP stopped reading it when it got to the `A`.  You could also say `intval(x, 16)` to parse the hexadecimal number, but since you're using the result as a string, hexdec is probably a teeny tiny bit faster.

As an unrelated note of caution, many programming languages treat numbers starting with 0 as octal rather than decimal.  If you say `$myvar = 031;`, `$myvar` will be set to `25`.  This also applies to JavaScript as well as its `parseInt` function.  In PHP, since `(int)` and `intval` default to base 10, `intval('031')` will be `31`.  However, `intval('031', 0)` will be `25` because the second parameter, `0`, tells `intval` to autodetect the base.

Answer (score 1):

Stop casting an alphanumeric string as an integer if you want the string to remain intact.  Why are you doing that?  Also, and more importantly, you need to escape your raw input, at the very least.  Call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on it before passing it to `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of student.IDNO in the database? Casting `$_GET['id']` to an int is going to make it just "3", which seems like not what you want

Answer (score 0):

`(int)03A43` will output `3`. Are you sure that's an `A` in there?

On the other hand, `$_GET[]` will always be a string. Casting a string as an int will remove the leading `0`. If you need the leading `0` just don't cast it, leave the string as it is.

Comment: yes there is an A, id number is composed of letters and numbers

Comment: Then the id type in the DB is a VARCHAR, am I right? If so, then don't cast it as an INT, why would you do that? Also, quote your query "... ='".$_GET['id']."'...;"